# replacing create_function() with something else for PHP8

Tags: php, wordpress, php-8, create-function

So I have a plugin that was working fine previously, but for a few days now it is throwing me an error as:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function create_function()

After a bit of searching, I found out that this is because `create_function()` is deprecated in PHP 8.

Now the exact line that causes the issue is this:

```
$callback_2 = create_function('$matches', 'return "[" . str_replace("|", "", $matches[1]) . "]";');
```

I tried changing this to:

```php
$callback_2 = function(){
 ('$matches', return "[" . str_replace("|", "", $matches[1]) . "]";);
}
```

But it's not working. So it would be great if someone could point me in the right direction also I am very new to PHP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```php
$callback_2 = function($matches) {
    return "[" . str_replace("|", "", $matches[1]) . "]";
};
```